# How to insert a value of id in a querySelector?

Tags: javascript

I have this code in html:

```
<div class="bet_balance">
    <span>Balance:
        <strong><b id="balance_r" style="">44</b> <b class="balance_type"></b></strong>
    </span>
    <i id="balance_update"></i>
</div>
```

And this code in JS:

```
document.querySelector('#message_text').value = '/send 1327877 **#balance_r**';
```

How i can take value of id(balance_r),and to put them in this querySelector after value '/send 1327877'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('#message_text').value = '/send 1327877 ' + document.getElementById('balance_r').innerText;
```